# I am writing automation script on one website and login credentials are fetching from excel file and getting this error

Tags: excel, selenium, robotframework, data-driven-tests, automation-testing

- Error which I am getting

---

---

[ ERROR ] [ DataDriver ] Error in robot file:
File "C:\Users\KARAN\PycharmProjects\OpencartFF\Testcases\RunOC.robot", line 0

[ ERROR ] In source file:
File "C:\Users\KARAN\PycharmProjects\OpencartFF\Testcases../TestData/Login3.xls", line 0

[ ERROR ] Calling method '_start_suite' of listener 'DataDriver' failed: ImportError: Requirements (pandas, xlrd) for XLS support are not installed.
Use 'pip install -U robotframework-datadriver[XLS]' to install XLS support.

---

I already had this xls support install though getting this above error.

### My code

---

*** Settings ***

Library    SeleniumLibrary

Resource   ../Resources/OCKeywords.robot

Library     DataDriver  ../TestData/Login3.xls    sheet_name=Sheet1

Suite Setup    open my browser      ${siteurl}      ${browser}

Suite Teardown    Close my browser

Test Template    Login from excel file

*** Variables ***

${browser}      chrome

${siteurl}     http://automationpractice.com/index.php

*** Testcases ***

Login from excel using  ${SE}   ${SP}

*** Keywords ***

Login from excel file

```
[Arguments]    ${SE}    ${SP}

Enter email for signin    ${SE}

Enter password for signin   ${SP}

Click signin button
```

Comment: It would really help if you format your question in a way that is readable.

Comment: @Darkproduct I hope it is more readable now.